# ASP.Net Html.TextBox with Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass 2 date parameters from the View to the Controller.

#### View

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Date From:</p>
            @Html.TextBox("ExpDateFrom", ViewBag.ExpDateFrom as DateTime)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Date To:</p>
            @Html.TextBox("ExpDateTo", ViewBag.ExpDateTo as DateTime)
            <input type="submit" value="Find" />
        </div>
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, DateTime dateOfExposureFrom, DateTime dateOfExposureTo)
```

Obviously right now this isn't going to work. I'm not even sure if you should use Html.TextBox for this, but even if you can there is an issue with using DateTime because it is not nullable.

How do I handle this? If I need to completely rework my approach that is fine. I just need to pass 2 date parameters from a view to a controller.

Comment: You can use model to follow the pattern model - view - controller, and let framework handle rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use reusable model - this will make things easier during further development.

```
public class SearchModel 
{
public string SortOrder { get; set; }
public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
public string SearchString { get; set; }
public int? Page { get; set; }
public DateTime DateOfExposureFrom { get; set; }
public DateTime DateOfExposureTo { get; set; }
}
```

Then controller

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel model)
```

Then view

```
@model SearchModel

<div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Date From:</p>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfExposureFrom, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: How can I use this if I am already using another model in the view?

Comment: You have 2 options. Add SearchModel to model you are using in view or stick to your initial solution, but in this case its easier to pass datetime to controller as string and convert it to datetime especially if you are building multi language site nad intent to switch app culture.

Comment: I think sending it as a string and then converting to datetime might be the approach I take then. Thank you a ton for the help.